# Subfield() for bulk dataset

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a field called `Subject Error` which measures which subjects students earned below passing grade.

Currently, the value spits out with one raw value:

```
Count of 23: English
Count of 10: Math; Science 
Count of 2: English; Math; Social Studies
```

How can I separate semi-colon from each subject so my analysis will show below:

```
Count of 24: English 
Count of 11: Math
Count of 10: Science
Count of 1: Social Studies
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Is there are relation between the records? For example if the data is `Count of 10: Math; Science` and `Count of 2: Math; English` then the final result (for `Math`) will be `Count of 12: Math` (summing the first `Count of 10` and the second `Count of 2`) or the question is just to split the subjects one per row?

Comment: Yep, the objective is not only to split the semi-colon but also to sum the matching result. Because currently it spits out as one long list

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how you could do it:

```
/* ==== STEP 1 ==== */
[data]:
Load * Inline [
Subject Error
Count of 23: English
Count of 10: Math; Science 
Count of 2: English; Math; Social Studies
];


[data 1]:
Load
    [Subject Error]
  , [Start]
  , /* ==== STEP 4 ==== */ KeepChar([Start], '0123456789') as [Student Count]
  , /* ==== STEP 5 ==== */ Trim(SubField([End], ';')) as [Subject]
;
Load
    [Subject Error]
  , /* ==== STEP 2 ==== */ Mid([Subject Error], 1, Index([Subject Error], ':')) as [Start]
  , /* ==== STEP 3 ==== */ SubField([Subject Error], ':', 2) as [End]
Resident [data];

Drop Table [data];


/* ==== STEP 7 ==== */
Join ([data 1])
Load
    [Subject]
  , /* ==== STEP 6 ==== */ Sum([Student Count]) as [Total Student Count]
Resident [data 1]
  Group By [Subject]
;


[data 2]:
Load Distinct
    /* ==== STEP 8 ==== */ 'Count of ' & [Total Student Count] & ': ' & [Subject] as [Final]
Resident [data 1];

Drop Table [data 1];
```

Here's how this works:

- Step 1: I load the data here. I'm just using an Inline table but you will load your data from a file/database/API presumably.
- Step 2: I use the [`Index()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/Index.htm) to find where the colon character is in the `[Subject Error]` field. That result is used in the [`Mid()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/Mid.htm) to grab just the `Count of n:'` part of the field. I name this new field `[Start]`.
- Step 3: I use the [`SubField()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm) to get the list of subjects that come after the colon character in the `[Subject Error]` field. I name this new field `[End]`.
- Step 4: Building off of the previous table in a [preceding load](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/load-data-from-previously-loaded-table.htm#anchor-3), I then use the [`KeepChar()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/KeepChar.htm) to just grab the numbers from the `Count of n:'` string in the `[Start]` field so that I can `Sum()` them in Step 6. I name this new field `[Student Count]`.
- Step 5: I use the `SubField()` function to create a new record for each subject that gets split out on the semicolon character. Normally, you have the utilize the third parameter of the `SubField()` function to specify which split-out item to return but in the Data Load Editor you can omit that third parameter, which will result in a new row for each split-out item. (See **Script Example 2** on the [examples section of the Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm#anchor-1) for this function.) I name this new field `[Subject]`.
- Step 6: In a separate table load, I use the [`Sum()` aggregation function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/AggregationFunctions/sum.htm) to sum up the values in the `[Student Count]` field. I group these summations on the `[Subject]` field using the `Group By` clause so that I get a total count of student for each subject. I name this new field `[Total Student Count]`.
- Step 7: That separate table gets `Join`ed back in to the previous table so that I can use the new `[Total Student Count]` along with the other fields in the final step.
- Step 8: Finally, in a new table, I use the [ampersand operator `&`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/Operators/StringOperators.htm#anchor-1) for string concatenation to combine the string `Count of` , the `[Total Student Count]` field, the colon character `:`, and then the `[Subject]` field. Note that I use the `Distinct` keyword in the load statement so that I am just getting one row per subject.

That should result in the desired output:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense table output]